# BaseController.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback, object): no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, localization

I am trying to implement BaseController class which inherits from Controller but I got a '**BaseController.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback, object): no suitable method found to override**' error. What I am doing wrong. Here is the code:

public class BaseController : Controller
    {

```
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string cultureName = null;

        // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cultureCookie != null)
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
        else
            cultureName = Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 ? Request.UserLanguages[0] : null; 

        // Validate culture name
        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); 

        // Modify current thread's cultures            
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }


}
```

By the way I got the code from this blog:
http://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/ but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MVC you are using?

You should reference System.Web.MVC from package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.4 if you are using MVC5

It looks Controller does not have method BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state).

Comment: I don't know how to check for the MVC version. I inherited the project from another developer who left the company. There is no reference folder so I can check for the version of System.Web.MVC

Comment: Sorry for late response, you can check the Nuget Package for your Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc library